# Can SAP Business One Query a View?

Tags: sql, sapb1

I built a view on MSSQL Management Studio and then I have a query to reference that view. It works fine on Management Studio. However, it would appear that B1 cannot query a view. Is that true? If there is a way, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you sure can use views in a query within the SAP Business One client. Format your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[view_name]
```